# how do I add a new page to FAQ

Tags: customer, magento-1.5

I added a new page but I cannot get it to show up on the footer part of the page where I have the other information such as policy , privacy and so on. Have created the page successfully but i cannot get it to show up so a customer can click on it to read the information.

Answer (score 1):

you should find the cms block of your footer and insert and html link to the new page. You should find it in CMS -> Static Blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can put your links in footer in two process

1)In your already existing Static Block `Footer Links/Footer Links Company` create another link by giving this code

`<li><a href="{{store direct_url="your_required_url"}}">Your_page_name</a></li>` and save the block you can see your required page link in footer.

2)Build a Static Block and put your required links into that block and call that block in `footer.phtml` using this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('links')->toHtml() ?>
```

Hope this helps.